# Adicionar elementos em Dicionario e converte-los para string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Olá,

estou fazendo uns testes com Scraping utilizando a biblioteca "BeautifulSoup" do python e me surgiu uma duvida. Eu consegui extrair algumas informações do um site como titulo do produto, sku, e as informações técnicas dele, porem eu precisava adicionar isso em um dicionario e depois converter esses resultados para string.

segue o codigo que estou usando:

```
titulo=soup.find(class_='fbits-produto-nome prodTitle title').get_text()

sku=soup.find(class_='fbits-sku').get_text()


descri=soup.find('div',{'class':'conteudoAbasProduto'}).children.get_text()

desc={'titulo':titulo,'sku':sku,'descri':descri}

print(desc)"
```

porem quando imprimo ele me traz esse resultado:

> "AttributeError: 'list_iterator' object has no attribute 'get_text"

podem me ajudar?

Comment: se você printar as variáveis: titulo, sku, descri individualmente elas estão com os dados?

Comment: estão sim, porém quando eu printo o dicionario ele não traz nada

Answer (score 0):

```py
descricao=soup.find('div',{'class':'conteudoAbasProduto'}).children
```

A variável `descricao` acima retorna um objeto `list iterator`:

```py
<list_iterator object at 0x7f9c14b99908>
```

O texto que você procura está contido em um dos elementos da variável `descricao`. Dessa forma, é necessário iterar nessa variável. Caso não seja possível iterar diretamente através de um `for`, basta fazer um cast `list(descricao)`.

Por fim, você pode imprimir cada um dos elementos da lista gerada e verificar em qual caso o método `getText()` está disponível:

```py
for element in descricao:
    try:
        element.getText()
        print(element)
    except AttributeError:
        continue
```